# Use remote storage for a subset of WSUS clients

Tags: windows, remote, wsus

I have a WSUS server configured to manage and serve updates from local storage for all clients.

Is it possible to configure WSUS to still manage all updates, but force some clients to download the updates directly from Microsoft (using remote storage), without affecting other clients?

Edit: The place of the required configuration changes is not important, be it server or client side, both would be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself:

This is not possible.

The only way to achieve this is to set up an additional replica-downstreamserver with remote storage configured, while the original server remains with local storage. Clients which should download updates from microsoft have then to be pointed to the replica server.